# StatefulConsumerWidget builds infinitely

Tags: flutter, riverpod

The print function in the build method is executed indefinitely. Is this a problem? And if so, how do I fix it? When I changed StatefulConsumerWidget to StatefulWidget and enclosed Scaffold in Consumer, this problem did not occur.　Below is my code.
"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." and I deleted the Notifier code once I couldn't edit it.

HomeScreen,Notifier

```
class HomeScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends ConsumerState<HomeScreen> {
  void showEndDrawer(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build");
    final user = ref.watch(userProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(actions: [
        Builder(builder: (context) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.0),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user!.profileImagePath),
              ),
              onPressed: () => showEndDrawer(context),
            ),
          );
        })
      ]),
      endDrawer: const ProfileDrawer(),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text("Hey"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final userProvider =
    NotifierProvider<UserModelNotifier, UserModel?>(UserModelNotifier.new);

class UserModelNotifier extends Notifier<UserModel?> {
  @override
  UserModel? build() {
    return null;
  }

  void update(UserModel userModel) {
    state = userModel;
  }
}
```

MyApp

```
lass MyApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {
  UserModel? userModel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final authData = ref.read(authStateChangeProvider);
    if (authData is AsyncValue<User> && authData.value != null) {
      getData(ref, authData.value!);
    }
  }

  void getData(WidgetRef ref, User data) async {
    final fetchedUserModel = await ref
        .watch(authControllerProvider.notifier)
        .getUserData(data.uid)
        .first;
    setState(() {
      userModel = fetchedUserModel;
    });
    ref.read(userProvider.notifier).update(fetchedUserModel);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ref.watch(authStateChangeProvider).when(
          data: (data) => MaterialApp.router(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'nijimas',
            theme: MyColors.myAppTheme,
            routerDelegate: RoutemasterDelegate(
              routesBuilder: (context) {
                if (data != null) {
                  getData(ref, data);
                  if (userModel != null) {
                    return loggedInRoute;
                  }
                }
                return loggedOutRoute;
              },
            ),
            routeInformationParser: const RoutemasterParser(),
          ),
          error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(error: error.toString()),
          loading: () => const Loader(),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use the method `UserModelNotifier.update`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I use update with the getData method in MyApp.I had to remove Notifier once the amount of code became too much. I use it for this MyApp and other methods for GoogleSignIn.

Comment: Fine. What does your `UserModel` look like?

Comment: Not sure about the main issue. But I would use `read` instead of `watch` inside `getData`. Also why do you use setState() with userModel together with `userProvider`?  I would just use `userProvider`, it should be enough

Comment: @Reble UserModel class does not have any methods of its own creation, but is an execution of a VSCode extension, genereta Data Class. There are no other features.

Comment: @OlegBezr Thanks for your comment. I will take your advice and try different things.